# Some app could not data such as facebook load when uses mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I installed a mitmproxy on MacOS and run like

```
$ mitmweb -p 9999
```

Then I open an Ipad and goto Wifi -> manual setting proxy.

```
Server: 192.168.1.202
Port: 9999
```

Chrome worked fine but some app can not load the content such as Facebook, App Store.
In console I got some message like:

```
192.168.1.29:58506: clientconnect
192.168.1.29:58506: clientdisconnect
192.168.1.29:58507: clientconnect
192.168.1.29:58507: clientdisconnect
```

The version is:

```
Mitmproxy: 6.0.0.dev (+19, commit 7b638f1)
Python:    3.7.5
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
Platform:  Darwin-19.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install mitmproxy CA certificate on your iPad? https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/

Comment: I installed already! If not install, other https websites should not able to access. In this case, just some apps was happened.